# How to compare two xmls who have same content, but different attribute orders?

Tags: xml, scala

```
scala> val xml1 = <a method="1" href="2" ref="3" onclick="4">Hello</a>
xml1: scala.xml.Elem = <a ref="3" href="2" onclick="4" method="1">Hello</a>

scala> val xml2 = <a ref="3" href="2" onclick="4" method="1">Hello</a>
xml2: scala.xml.Elem = <a href="2" ref="3" onclick="4" method="1">Hello</a>

scala> xml1 == xml2
res8: Boolean = false
```

As the sample, `xml1` and `xml2` have same content, but the attributes have different orders, and the result is `false`. So, how to compare such xmls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the tool for you:

[xml-test: A diff-like tool for XML](http://code.google.com/p/xml-test/)